# Target-specific launch screen

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, launch-screen

I have an existing iOS app with a single target and a corresponding `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

In the same Xcode project I have created a new target (e.g `newtarget`) by duplicating the initial one. I also have created a new launch screen `LaunchScreen-newtarget.storyboard` (added as a resource of this target) which is referenced in the new target's plist file (in `Launch screen interface file base name`).

But I only see a black screen instead of the launch screen when running this target.

How can I use a separate launch screen for my new target?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure the launch screen is added as a resource for the new target and then update the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key (also known as `Launch screen interface file base name`) in the new target's plist file to say `LaunchScreen-newtarget`.

Comment: I have re-created the target from scratch and now it works, so I suspect that XCode was in some inconsistent state. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I was about to pull out my hair when you reminded me that I did not add this screen to my new target under build settings. +1

Comment: is it possible to have scheme-specific launch screen? my schemes have same plist